# Why is it discouraged developer directly to manipulate element instead of using BuildContext in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, interface, flutter-dependencies

when I read Flutter document, I cannot understand "BuildContextobjects are actually Element objects. The BuildContextinterface is used to discourage direct manipulation of Element objects."

I am wondering that is this interface is public and can be implemented other class?